# Gulp Watch task

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-less

I have the following gulp tasks:

```
gulp.task('less', function() {
    gulp.src('public/stylesheets/**/*.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(concat('styles.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/public'))
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('public/stylesheets/**/*.{css,less}', ['less']);
});
```

and both of them are included in my `default` task (among others):

```
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
    gulp.start('less','watch');
});
```

When I run `gulp` everything works fine. All my `.less` files are compiled into one minified .css file.

Now I make a change in any less file and see the output

```
[14:11:27] Starting 'less'...
[14:11:27] Finished 'less' after 1.49 ms
```

but my minified css file hasn't changed. Just for testing purposed I removed the minify/concat, but it had the same effect. The `less` task is working fine within the default task, but when started through `watch` nothing happens.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Try using watch like this:

```
gulp.watch([your glob], function () {
    gulp.start(['less']);
});
```

I also believe that you need to remove `.css` from your glob pattern. Compiling LESS would produce CSS which would also trigger the watcher.